# Laravel session ID not persistent on server

Tags: php, laravel, session

Hi im currently having trouble with my laravel app on server side, it seems that the session is always regenerating. it is running perfectly on local xampp environment.

im using laravel 8.83, default session.php file. i've check the files under storage/framework/sessions/ were created. below are sample code i use to check the session.

```
Route::get('/sesget',function(){
    $myname = array('my','name');

    session()->put('name', $myname);
    session()->save();
    $ba = session('name');
    ad($myname);        
    
    ad($ba);
    
    ad(session()->all());
    
    return redirect('/sescheck');
});

Route::get('/sescheck',function(){
    $name = session()->get('name');
    ad(session()->all());
    ad($name);
    exit();
});
```

i have also tried to wrap and unwrap all route into web, check my middleware and everything is not working.

Answer (score -1):

After trying 101 ways found on the internet, none were successful. What i did was remove one of the dependency on composer which is fruitcake/laravel-cors. Make sure to also remove it from kernel.php.

This works for me for now.

Comment: Removing CORS protections is **Extremely Dangerous** step to take and will likely create a **SIGNIFICANT SECURITY RISK**. Please be very sure this is really what you want to do and that you fully understand all of the risks involved. You will need to have mitigate all of the risks that removing CORS protection causes. If it were me, I would continue to research the issue and solve this by any other means, even if it cost me money to resolve it. I cannot stress enough how big of a security issue you have opened.